# Getting chinese characters when reading an English pdf using PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm reading page 41 of [this](https://efast2-filings-public.s3.amazonaws.com/prd/2013/09/13/20130913143132P030383431491001.pdf) pdf file using the following code:

```
pageObj = PyPDF2.PdfReader(open(path_to_the_file, 'rb')).pages# creating a pdf reader object
page_41=pageObj[40].extract_text()
```

But part of What I get is this:

䩯桮⁈慮捯捫⁕十 䱩晥獴祬攠䅧杲敳獩癥 102,734

䩯桮⁈慮捯捫⁕十 䱩晥獴祬攠䝲潷瑨 159,791

䩯桮⁈慮捯捫⁕十 䱩晥獴祬攠䉡污湣敤 285,623

䩯桮⁈慮捯捫⁕十 䱩晥獴祬攠䵯摥牡瑥 9,130

䩯桮⁈慮捯捫⁕十 䱩晥獴祬攠䍯湳敲癡瑩癥 ㌰ⰶ㔰

What should I do to extract correctly? 5% of PDFs get these weird characters.

Update: I now tried with PyMuPDF, and it extracted it well. The problem also seems to be related to PyPDF (I've tried pypdf too).

Comment: Since you have the same information on page 40, why worry about it?

Comment: Try `pageObj[40].extractText().encode('ascii', 'ignore')` this will remove the special characters.

Comment: @TimRoberts Because 1)Not every pdf has that page (less than 1% of pdfs), and 2)ocr is inefficient as I'm reading tens of thousands of pdfs.

Comment: I've filed an issue on pypdf: [extract_text leads to Chinese characters instead of ASCII](https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/issues/1672).

Comment: @MartinThoma Thank you. I hope it gets resolved soon as my work is dependent on that.

Comment: @MartinThoma Also, the gs fix did not work.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I hope @pubpub-zz finds some time to look into it. Otherwise I can only recommend to look at other libraries : https://github.com/py-pdf/benchmarks

Answer (score -1):

You may try pdfplumber.
I use it to successfully read PDF file with Chinese characters.

Install the package:

```
pip install pdfplumber
```

The code to read a PDF file with its path:

```
import pdfplumber

def extract_PDF_file(path):
    with pdfplumber.open(path) as pdf:
    content = ''
    for i in range(len(pdf.pages)):
        page = pdf.pages[i]
        page_content = '\n'.join(page.extract_text().split('\n')[:-1])
        content = content + page_content
    print(content)
```